# Many types of String (ByteString)

Tags: haskell, bytestring

I wish to compress my application's network traffic.

According to the (latest?) ["Haskell Popularity Rankings"](http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2009/08/29/haskell-popularity-rankings-september-2009/), [zlib](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/zlib/0.5.2.0/doc/html/Codec-Compression-Zlib.html#1) seems to be a pretty popular solution. zlib's interface uses `ByteString`s:

```
compress :: ByteString -> ByteString
decompress :: ByteString -> ByteString
```

I am using regular `String`s, which are also the data types used by `read`, `show`, and `Network.Socket`:

```
sendTo :: Socket -> String -> SockAddr -> IO Int
recvFrom :: Socket -> Int -> IO (String, Int, SockAddr)
```

So to compress my strings, I need some way to convert a `String` to a `ByteString` and vice-versa.
With [hoogle](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/hoogle/)'s help, I found:

```
Data.ByteString.Char8 pack :: String -> ByteString
```

Trying to use it:

```
Prelude Codec.Compression.Zlib Data.ByteString.Char8> compress (pack "boo")

<interactive>:1:10:
    Couldn't match expected type `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString'
           against inferred type `ByteString'
    In the first argument of `compress', namely `(pack "boo")'
    In the expression: compress (pack "boo")
In the definition of `it': it = compress (pack "boo")
```

Fails, because (?) there are different types of `ByteString` ?

So basically:

- Are there several types of `ByteString`? What types, and why?
- What's "the" way to convert `String`s to `ByteString`s?

Btw, I found that it does work with `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8`'s `ByteString`, but I'm still intrigued.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two kinds of bytestrings: strict (defined in [Data.Bytestring.Internal](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/0.9.1.4/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Internal.html)) and lazy (defined in [Data.Bytestring.Lazy.Internal](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/0.9.1.4/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Lazy-Internal.html)). zlib uses lazy bytestrings, as you've discovered.

Comment: No. `Char8` modules just give a different interface to the same bytestrings.

Answer (score 8):

The function you're looking for is:

```
import Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS

lazyToStrictBS :: LBS.ByteString -> BS.ByteString
lazyToStrictBS x = BS.concat $ LBS.toChunks x
```

I expect it can be written more concisely without the x.  (i.e. point-free, but I'm new to Haskell.)

Comment: like `lazyToStrictBS = BS.concat . LBS.toChunks`

Answer (score 6):

A more efficient mechanism might be to switch to a full bytestring-based layer:

- network.bytestring for bytestring sockets
- lazy bytestrings for compressoin
- binary of bytestring-show to replace Show/Read

Comment: @dons: it appears that I will need to use Network.Socket.ByteString.Lazy for compatibility with zlib, but unlike Network.Socket.ByteString, it doesn't implement sendTo and recvFrom, making it unsuitable for me.

Comment: I don't think it will be too hard for you to stream chunks of lazy bytestrings into a socket taking individual ones. It's essentially mapM_ send . fromChunks

Comment: @dons: when using UDP it will actually make a difference if you send your packet in whole or in chunks. but are you also saying that conversion between lazy and strict bytestring is easy? that would be useful to know..

Comment: @yairchu - the functions `toChunks` and `fromChunks` in `Data.ByteString.Lazy` convert between strict and lazy bytestrings.